# Is Bash a language or a program?

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I've seen it listed as a scripting language and other sources state that its just a program that runs predefined scripts in the bin whatever folder. So my question is are the bash commands on every system the same so is bash a scripting language or is it a program and the commands depent on the system you're using.

Cheers

Comment: "the commands depent on the system you're using" — That may even depend on the _version_ of the interpreter that is on a given machine. When you come across a script posted on the net, and the author of the script had a newer version of the interpreter on their machine than you on yours, then you may not be able to run the script, due to your older version interpreter may not understand everything in it. (This may not happen often, but it's not an impossibility.)

Answer (score 3):

From the quite good [Wikipedia page on Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)):

> Bash is a command processor that typically runs in a text window where the user types commands that cause actions. Bash can also read and execute commands from a file, called a shell script. Like all Unix shells, it supports filename globbing (wildcard matching), piping, here documents, command substitution, variables, and control structures for condition-testing and iteration. The keywords, syntax, dynamically scoped variables and other basic features of the language are all copied from sh. Other features, e.g., history, are copied from csh and ksh. Bash is a POSIX-compliant shell, but with a number of extensions.

- Bash is included with Ubuntu, but is NOT the default shell ([dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash) is)
- Bash is generally portable between systems, *but that's not guaranteed*. For true portability, stick to the [POSIX](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/posix.html#:%7E:text=POSIX%20stands%20for%20Portable%20Operating,port%20applications%20between%20hardware%20platforms.) standard.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is a scripting language. However, a language without an implementation is boring: you can write programs in it, but you cannot run them.

In order to run programs written in Bash, you need a program which can process those programs. This program happens to also be called Bash.

So, the answer is: both.